# Is this valid code in java

Tags: java, variables

I have what may be a simple question but I can't seem to find an answer. Can variables be assigned with **:** (colon) in java. Like in this code below:

```
 for(String token: tokens) {
  System.out.println(token);
```

I saw this on one of the question boards for a different topic.

Thanks for responding.

Comment: Why not try compiling it and see for yourself?

Comment: For what version of Java are you asking?

Answer (score 4):

In this case the operator `:` is not an assignment; it represents the enhanced for loop added in Java 5. It basically means "for every String in the String array or String Iterable, use the String.

Answer (score 3):

This is called an enhanced for loop. From [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html):

```
class EnhancedForDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         int[] numbers = 
             {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
         for (int item : numbers) {
             System.out.println("Count is: " + item);
         }
    }
}
```

The output from this program:

```
Count is: 1
Count is: 2
Count is: 3
Count is: 4
Count is: 5
Count is: 6
Count is: 7
Count is: 8
Count is: 9
Count is: 10
```

Comment: Nit: Although this comment *shouldn't* apply to anyone, enhanced for-loops were added in [Java 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) (~ 2004). So for *old* versions of javac it could result in a syntax error ..

Comment: Cheers again guys, also read this up on docs.oracle. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is valid, assuming there is a collection of strings named `tokens`. Although, you're missing the closing `}`

Answer (score 0):

That's a "for-each" in Java. It reads like "for each token in tokens". The `tokens` variable is an `Iterable` collection. The code inside the loop repeats for each element from the collection.

Comment: Nit: It's not *simply* a "for-each", which also includes `for(;;)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special for loop in Java called for-each. What the statement for(String token: tokens) means is that iterate over the collection tokens & assign the values to the String variable token as you iterate.

The assignment via ':' works only in for each loop and not in any other constructs

Answer (score 0):

This is also known as a foreach loop which iterates through a collection.

There's a better example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)